# How to modify autocomplete input for not effect to css or html?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, popup, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to create a popup, i did whatever, it is not the main thing.

This is the situation, I add a autocompleted textbox in the popup and a textbox below of it with two buttons. But when I enter some input to textbox, it suggests me three of the most approximetly words, but it effects the other buttons and textbox, they are going down, I dont want it to do this. everything has to be stable, how can i handle this problem? For more information,screenshots are below.

Thanks...

[without entering a data to textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2l1s.jpg)

[after entering a data to textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tvJD.jpg)

Comment: attach pop up to body with z-index higher than other elements using absolute position?

Comment: popup is opening quite well, popup is not problem, problem is textbox in the popup, can I write some css for textbox or something?

Comment: can u post the code, could be something wrong in how u created the popup

Comment: posted!!.......

Comment: this >>  <ul class="list-group" ng-model="hidethis" ng-hide="hidethis">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="countrydata in filterCountry" ng-if="$index < 3" ng-click="fillTextbox(countrydata)">{{countrydata}}</li>
        </ul> could be attached to parent of input tag just below it with higher z-index and absolute positioning

Comment: or make positioning of <div class="ngdialog-buttons"> absolute

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header">X</div>
<form name="X" class="content">

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" ng-model="country" ng-change="complete(country)" class="form-control" />
        <ul class="list-group" ng-model="hidethis" ng-hide="hidethis">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="countrydata in filterCountry" ng-if="$index < 3" ng-click="fillTextbox(countrydata)">{{countrydata}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" placeholder="Quantity">

    <!-- Dialog Buttons -->
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="ngdialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click="">CANCEL</button>
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click="" ng-disabled="">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the source code of popup, it is called by another button from the page and opening with this style and html...